# ASP NET - INCORRECT ID

Tags: asp.net-core

I am trying to upload a document. The document loads without problem, the only detail that does not load where it should.

I have a list of several documents, and no matter how hard I try to load it to a specific document, it always ends up passing it the ID of the first document in the row.

[image]

@list.DocumentoMaster.IdDocumentoMaster It would be the master ID of the document to which it should be uploaded, and in the Foreach that ID appears well for each document. The problem comes when I load the document and SUBMIT the POST form.

[image]

For example if I try to load the 4th document, it immediately goes to the first document in the list, in this case "Birth Certificate".

[image]

That the ID of the first master of the first document in the row always arrives. I've tried various things and I've run out of ideas. HELP!!!

I put on Expiration column the IdDocumentMaster.
[image]
[image]

and my short JavaScript.
[image]

Comment: After the page rendering, try to use F12 developer tools to check the hidden field value (`@list.DocumentoMaster.IdDocumentoMaster` value), whether it is correct or not? Besides, are you using the DropDownList to trigger the upload function? If that is the case, can you share the related JavaScript script, perhaps the issue is related that.

Comment: IdDocumentoMaster comes with the correct ID. The problem is when this ID go to the C# Page. I add the JavaScript and the IdDocumentMaster.[Besides, are you using the DropDownList to trigger the upload function?] No, i just using a Form Post and i upload the file with IFormFile.

Comment: Try to set a break point in the Post method, after submitting the Form, whether the form data is correct or not? Besides, please check the onChnageEntidad() method, not sure whether the issue related it or not, if you want to use it to edit current row information, by using the `document.getElementById()` method, it will causes keep getting the value from the first row, because they might have the same id value per row, if the issue relate that, you have to find the current row first, then access the element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are trying to insert a new document but in fact you are doing an update on it.
When you do insert do not pass ID.
Use new object instead of existing object.

sample code.

```
using (DataClassesDataContext db = new DataClassesDataContext())
        {
            var existingDay =
              (from d in db.WeatherTBL
               where d.DateTime.ToString() == day.Date.ToString()
               select d).SingleOrDefault<WeatherTBL>();
            if (existingDay != null)
            {
                existingDay.Temp = day.Temp;
                existingDay.WindSpeed = day.WindSpeed;
                existingDay.Pressure = day.Pressure;
                existingDay.Humidity = day.Humidity;
                existingDay.Cloudiness = day.Cloudiness;
                existingDay.TypeRecip = day.TypeRecip;
                db.SubmitChanges();
            }
            else
            {
                WeatherTBL newDay = new WeatherTBL();
                newDay.DateTime = day.Date;
                newDay.Temp = day.Temp;
                newDay.WindSpeed = day.WindSpeed;
                newDay.Pressure = day.Pressure;
                newDay.Humidity = day.Humidity;
                newDay.Cloudiness = day.Cloudiness;
                newDay.TypeRecip = day.TypeRecip;
                db.WeatherTBL.InsertOnSubmit(newDay);
                db.SubmitChanges();
            }
        }
```

generate dynamic id like this

```
<input type="hidden"  name=@list.DocumentoMaster.IdDocumentoMaste id=@list.DocumentoMaster.IdDocumentoMaste />
```

so that you have unique name for each id.

Comment: I need the correct ID to reference the Master Document to which I will be uploading the file.

That Correct ID is not reaching the C # of the razor page, only the ID of the first of the row arrives.

Comment: How can i do this?